# replace core javascript scrollto with jquery animation

Tags: jquery, function, mobile, replace, scroll

Is it possible to replace a core Javascript function with a custom function?

For example I am using jQuery Mobile and it does an annoying 'jump' to the top of the page whenever a page transitions. I have found that this is because in the 'transitionPages' function it has this line

```
window.scrollTo( 0, $.mobile.defaultHomeScroll );
```

I'd like to leave the core jQm code alone, (for maintainence purposes) so despite the fact that I think this should have been written as an animation in the first place, what I'd like to do is something like this:-

- whenever javascript scrollTo is called
- dont do the default action
- do this nice animated jQuery version instead

So basically hijack the javascript native scrollTo function and replace it with something else?

Possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just set the native function to your own one to override it.
Basically:

```
window.scrollTo = YourAnimatedScrollFunction;
```

Keep in mind not to use the brackets for assigning the function, because that would execute it instead of assigning it. Also be sure that your custom function accepts the same parameters as the native function.